# Getting an file exists error while import into Hive using sqoop

Tags: import, hive, sqoop

I am trying to copy the retail_db database tables into hive database which I already created. When I execute the following code

```
sqoop import-all-tables \
--num-mappers 1 \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
--username=retail_dba \
--password=cloudera \
--hive-import \
--hive-overwrite \
--create-hive-table \
--outdir java_files \
--hive-database retail_stage
```

My Map-reduce job stops with the following error:

> ERROR tool.ImportAllTablesTool: Encountered IOException running import
>   job: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output
>   directory hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/categories
>   already exists

I am trying to copy the tables to hive database,Then why an existing file in cloudera caused the problem. Is there a way to ignore this error or overwrite the existing file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how `sqoop` imports job works:

- `sqoop` creates/imports data in `tmp` dir(`HDFS`) which is user's home dir(in your case it is `/user/cloudera`).
- Then copy data to its actual hive location (i.e., `/user/hive/wearhouse`.
- This `categories` dir should have exist before you ran import statements. so delete that dir or rename it if its important.

`hadoop fs -rmr /user/cloudera/categories`

OR

`hadoop fs -mv /user/cloudera/categories /user/cloudera/categories_1`

and re-run sqoop command!

So in short, Importing to `Hive` will use hdfs as the staging place and sqoop deletes staging dir `/user/cloudera/categories` after copying(sucessfully) to actual hdfs location - it is last stage of sqoop job to clean up staging/tmp files - so if you try to list the tmp staging dir, you won't find it.

After successful import: `hadoop fs -ls /user/cloudera/categories` - dir will not be there.

Answer (score 5):

Sqoop import to Hive works in 3 steps:

- Put data to HDFS
- Create Hive table if not exists
- Load data into Hive Table

You have not mentioned `--target-dir` or `--warehouse-dir`, so it will put data in  HDFS Home Directory which I believe `/user/cloudera/` in your case.

Now for a MySQL table `categories` you might have imported it earlier. So, `/user/cloudera/categories` directory exists and you are getting this exception.

Add any non-existing directory in `--taget-dir` like  `--taget-dir /user/cloudera/mysqldata`. Then sqoop will put all the Mysql Tables imported by above command in this location.

Comment: What in case of map-reduce re-attempt? In case oozie re-attempts the task, it throws directory already exists error.what can be done to correct it?

Comment: @Simrankaur You can use `--delete-target-dir`. It will delete <HDFS-target-dir> provided in command before writing data to this directory.

Comment: But I am not using target-dir, I am using --warehouse-dir. Would it delete it anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Based on answer #1 above, I found [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/186425/output-directory-already-exists-error-in-sqoop.html). I tried and it works.

So, just add --delete-target-dir

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `hive-import` and `hive-overwrite` at the same time.

The version I confirmed this issue is;

```
$ sqoop help import
```

> --hive-overwrite                            Overwrite existing data in
>                                                  the Hive table

```
$ sqoop version
```

> Sqoop 1.4.6-cdh5.13.0

ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22407835/927387