# Sqoop import-all-table to hive in specific database fails

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I'm executing the below sqoop command

```
sqoop import-all-tables -m 1 \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://nn01.itversity.com:3306/retail_db" \
--username=retail_dba \
--password=itversity \
--hive-import \
--hive-home /apps/hive/warehouse \
--hive-overwrite \
--hive-database grv_sqoop_import \
--create-hive-table \
--compress \
--compression-codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec \
--outdir java_files
```

As I have specified the `--hive-database` tables should be imported into it. But I'm getting following error:

```
ERROR tool.ImportAllTablesTool: Encountered IOException running import job: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Ou
tput directory hdfs://nn01.itversity.com:8020/user/gauravfrankly/categories already exists
```

Not able to understand why it's looking into `/user/gauravfrankly/` hdfs location.

Help in understanding this issue, what I'm missing here?

I have gone through [Getting an file exists error while import into Hive using sqoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38649071/getting-an-file-exists-error-while-import-into-hive-using-sqoop) as well but wanted to know, is there any other better way to handle it.

Comment: Have you tried removing `--create-hive-table` this and running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When You import data to HDFS as Hive table, Sqoop first creates a staging area in you home directory(your case `/user/gauravfrankly/`) with same folder name and it then moves data to the hive directory.

So there should not be any directory in home location with the same table name which you are importing as hive table. if it is there it will give you same error.

Solution is to remove the directory from home location and then try again.

Note: this is only when you import as hive table, no staging happens when you are importing to HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

You could try these:

- Remove this: `--create-hive-table`   If set, then the job will fail if the target hive
  table exits. By default this property is false. 
  And add this: `--hive-overwrite`   Overwrite existing data in the Hive table.
- Provide this: `--warehouse-dir <dir>`    HDFS parent for table destination.

Comment: I've checked in my grv_sqoop_import database in hive no tables has been created, so I don't see a problem with --create-hive-table. I've get it done by removing /user/gauravfrankly/categories, after removing it command worked well.

Comment: @Gauravverma yes thats the hdfs location where data is stored, `-rm -r` that location and it will be done.