# Sqoop import strange error

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh, sqoop

I have a hive external table `n1` whose location is set to `/user/cloudera/n1`. I also have a MySQL table whose name is also `n1`. Now when I try to import `n1` (MySQL) as `n2` (Hive), I get this strange error `/user/cloudera/n1 already exists`.

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sqoop import --table n1 --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db --username root --password cloudera --hive-import --hive-table n2 -m 1

18/02/08 06:34:05 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/n1 already exists
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:146)
```

Comment: Do you want to overwrite the table in hive ? or append ?

Comment: The point is neither overwriting nor appending.

Comment: Remove the hdfs directory and rerun the job .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38649071/getting-an-file-exists-error-while-import-into-hive-using-sqoop http://www.gchandra.com/error-messages/sqoop-mapred-filealreadyexistsexception-output-directory.html

Comment: Hi Roh, thanks for trying to help. But I should ask you to read the question carefully along with table names. The table I am trying to import is `n1` as `n2`. Now read the error.

Comment: I see whats the issue is now, Can you try adding the --table after the --connect ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not strange this is how Sqoop works. When you import a table to hive using Sqoop, it will create a staging file in the user home directory in the name of the table, in ur case it is `/user/cloudera/n1` this is what the issue.

You should either move ur external table path or you should import table in some other directory using `--targer-dir` and then create hive table over it.